# Angular2: Can't find package after npm install

Tags: angular, npm, npm-install

I try to install several packages via npm install. For example:

```
npm install ng2-storage
```

The package is correctly installed in node_modules directory.

I try to import the library via:

```
import { StorageSettings } from 'ng2-storage';
```

But when I start npm start I get this error:

```
app/main.ts(3,33): error TS2307: Cannot find module 'ng2-storage'.
```

I have this problem with every third party package.

Update: Added it to my system-config:

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function(global) {
  // map tells the System loader where to look for things
  var map = {
    'app':                        'dist', // 'dist',
    '@angular':                   'node_modules/@angular',
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
    'rxjs':                       'node_modules/rxjs',
    'ng2-storage':                'node_modules/ng2-storage'
  };
  // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'app':                        { main: 'main.js',  defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs':                       { defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'ng2-storage':                { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
  };
  var ngPackageNames = [
    'common',
    'compiler',
    'core',
    'forms',
    'http',
    'platform-browser',
    'platform-browser-dynamic',
    'router',
    'router-deprecated',
    'upgrade',
  ];
  // Individual files (~300 requests):
  function packIndex(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }
  // Bundled (~40 requests):
  function packUmd(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/'+pkgName] = { main: 'bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }
  // Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
  var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;
  // Add package entries for angular packages
  ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);
  var config = {
    map: map,
    packages: packages
  };
  System.config(config);
})(this);
```

**main.ts**

```
import { StorageSettings } from 'ng2-storage';
```

Same problem...

Comment: Have you included the downloaded package in your index page?

Comment: No, I don't think it's necessary.. I've never need to include it manually when developing ionic apps..

Comment: or in your loader?

Answer (score 3):

You need to add third party packages to your `systemjs.config.js` file, that's where you tell your app where to look for files. For example, I installed `ng2-bootstrap` few minutes ago and I had to add this:

```
var map = {
'app': 'app', // 'dist',
'@angular': 'node_modules/@angular',
'angular2-in-memory-web-api': 'node_modules/angular2-in-memory-web-api',
'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs',
'moment': 'node_modules/moment',
'ng2-bootstrap': 'node_modules/ng2-bootstrap',
};

var packages = {
'app': { main: 'main.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' },
'angular2-in-memory-web-api': { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
'ng2-bootstrap': { main: 'ng2-bootstrap.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
'moment': { main: 'moment.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
};
```

Search your `node_modules` folder to see what you need to add for your libraries.

Comment: I've updated my system-config but no success.. Still the same problem..

Comment: @rakete Then I think it is a problem on `ng2-storage` end, maybe they haven't published an update for RC5/RC6 yet.

Comment: I'll try other packages and give you feedback ;-) thankyou anyway!

Comment: You're welcome, hope you will find a way to fix this.